# Edit image results in copies of file being created

Tags: images, media, cropping

I am encountering what appears to be a file duplication issue when using the "Edit image" function. In this case specifically I am cropping the image but any edit process should have the same effect.

When I edit the file, crop it and save it generates a new set of images (original and thumbnail sizes etc) with a timestamp inserted into the name along the lines of "J-BREEN-477102-e1458728537270.jpg", where "e1458728537270" is the timestamp.

I have tried this on three different servers with the latest 4.4.2 WordPress install, all plugins disabled and also with the TwentySixteen theme and the same thing happens on all of them.

Where it's causing a problem specifically is that I can see the new cropped image in the post when I edit it but on the front end I see the uncropped image. I have tried clearing browser cache etc so it's not an issue of caching, in the backend it is using the new file with the timestamp in it but on the front it is using the original un-timestamped version. I am getting the "large" image on the front end via [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/).

My initial question is does anyone else experience the same thing? My initial assumption was that perhaps the new srcset feature in WordPress was causing an issue but I've disabled that in functions.php just to rule that out but the issue still exists. I was thinking of filing a ticket on Wordpress.org but I thought I'd see if this is an issue others are experiencing first.

**Update:**

Apologies, I'm getting up to speed a bit more as to how WordPress handles files when using these image edit tools, it appears that the additional files with the timestamp is part of how WordPress handles these edits by default, the timestamped files are the newly edited (cropped) files. The original uncropped files are kept on the server so that you can restore back to these original uncropped files. However, I have tried putting the `define( 'IMAGE_EDIT_OVERWRITE', true );` constant into wp-config.php top prevent new files from being created but overwriting them instead, but I still see these files being created and I still get the old original file being shown on the front end as I explained earlier.

The code I'm using for 'get_the_post_thumbnail' is:

```
$roh_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($currid, 'large');
echo $roh_thumbnail;
```

`$currid` is a variable for the current post id.

Comment: If you crop a image, it must created a new file and its resized versions. That is the correct behaviour. It is not a issue at all. So, your problem may be in the use of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`. Can you show us the code your are using and the context where you are using it?

Comment: Thanks @cybmeta, I just added a little update to my original post content. I realised that this was actually expected behaviour for edited images. But I tried setting the constant so that edit images are overwritten but it still seems to be generating these files. I'll add another edit with the code I'm using for `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`.

Comment: @cybmeta Doh, sorry, I've just realised it's actually `get_the_post_thumbnail` that I'm using to get the thumbnail and not `wp_get_attachment_image_src`, I did have the latter in amongst my code but it was for use in a different image so I was getting confused with that.